# Error fetching data by GetX. Error on model define or else

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-http

I need to fetch Category Data from my custom made API. I create a model, controller for fetch data from API with help of getx, but it give me error. I don't know what is the problem. Can anybody help me out please?

Here is my `Category_slider.dart` file as a view

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:we_serve/controllers/CategoryController.dart';

import '../models/Category.dart';

class CategorySlider extends StatelessWidget {
  CategoryController categoryController = Get.put(CategoryController());
  
  // categoryController.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(categoryController);
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 8,
      ),
      // itemCount: categoryController.,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 120,

                    // width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF1818B4)))),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          // Text(
                          //   categoryController.category?.data![index].categoryName,
                          //   style: TextStyle(
                          //     color: Colors.black,
                          //   ),
                          // ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my `Category.dart` model file

```dart
class Category {
  List<Data>? data;

  Category({required this.data});

  Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int? id;
  String? image;
  String? categoryName;
  String? categoryDes;
  int? activation;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  Data(
      {required this.id,
      required this.image,
      required this.categoryName,
      required this.categoryDes,
      required this.activation,
      required this.createdAt,
      required this.updatedAt});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    image = json['image'];
    categoryName = json['category_name'];
    categoryDes = json['category_des'];
    activation = json['activation'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['category_name'] = this.categoryName;
    data['category_des'] = this.categoryDes;
    data['activation'] = this.activation;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here is my Controller `CategoryController.dart` file

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:we_serve/models/Category.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class CategoryController extends GetxController{
  var isLoading = false.obs;
  Category? _category;

  // Category? get category => _category;

  fetchData() async {
    try{
      isLoading(true);
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.tryParse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category')!);
      // print(response.statusCode);
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
        // print(result);
        _category = Category.fromJson(result);
      }else{
        print("Error Fetching data");
      }
    }catch(e){
      print("Error while getting data is $e");
    }finally{
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }


}
```

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category` returning this json file

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "image": "public/category_images/U5WWF8C0Pfz3dF44ejs7XkguuNoynsgYKO3CjpxY.jpg",
            "category_name": "test 1",
            "category_des": "test category 1",
            "activation": 1,
            "created_at": "2023-07-19T09:58:32.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-07-19T09:58:32.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "image": "public/category_images/MBMi7FgEo1wlEDR4QbZRdRv6T6xWLUL2yddoMcg6.jpg",
            "category_name": "test 2",
            "category_des": "test category 2",
            "activation": 1,
            "created_at": "2023-07-19T09:58:53.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-07-19T09:58:53.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "image": "public/category_images/oN8UZu9v6B504IfFbvPeSWEI3IvWGR8Rc1R5t1WP.jpg",
            "category_name": "test 3",
            "category_des": "test category 3",
            "activation": 1,
            "created_at": "2023-07-19T09:59:04.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-07-19T10:10:03.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know how to solve this, but it seems that in controller `_category = Category.fromJson(result);` this line of code doesn't work or doesn't store the data into `_category` list. I am not sure but just assuming there is some problem in model or controller.

Comment: can you provide the result from the 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category'?

Comment: i have added the result of that link on main post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as model

```
import 'dart:convert';

Category categoryFromJson(String str) => Category.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String categoryToJson(Category data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Category {
    List<Datum>? data;

    Category({
        this.data,
    });

    factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Category(
        data: json["data"] == null ? [] : List<Datum>.from(json["data"]!.map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": data == null ? [] : List<dynamic>.from(data!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    int? id;
    String? image;
    String? categoryName;
    String? categoryDes;
    int? activation;
    DateTime? createdAt;
    DateTime? updatedAt;

    Datum({
        this.id,
        this.image,
        this.categoryName,
        this.categoryDes,
        this.activation,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
    });

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        id: json["id"],
        image: json["image"],
        categoryName: json["category_name"],
        categoryDes: json["category_des"],
        activation: json["activation"],
        createdAt: json["created_at"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: json["updated_at"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "image": image,
        "category_name": categoryName,
        "category_des": categoryDes,
        "activation": activation,
        "created_at": createdAt?.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt?.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```

then for the controller inside try putting this

```
class CategoryController extends GetxController{
  var isLoading = false.obs;
  Rx<Category> _category = Category().obs;

  // Category? get category => _category;

  fetchData() async {
    try{
      isLoading(true);
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.tryParse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category')!);
      // print(response.statusCode);
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
        // print(result);
        _category.value = Category.fromJson(result);
       // try to add update()
        update();
      }else{
        print("Error Fetching data");
      }
    }catch(e){
      print("Error while getting data is $e");
    }finally{
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }


}
```

I hope this helps i think try to change the model for now

**Update:**

try wrp the code like this

```
This is for GetBuilder
// This particular builder is good for heavy widgets
// and for the state to change is need to add update();
// e.g.
// variable.value = "change";
// update(); // Require to add update below.
// for every states variables. 
   return GetBuilder<CategoryController>(
     init: CategoryController(),
     builder:(controller){
        return WidgetSome();
      }
    );
```

The other one is OBX

```
  // This on is good for light states changes in ui unlike getbuilder
  // as sample variable is like this
  // variable("change");
  // But i usually use GetBuilder but still depends on you.
  return Obx(
    ()=> 
      WidgetSome(),
  );
```

for http to add headers is simple it's already indicate on the package you used although need to type them like this,

```
final header = {
       'Content-type': 'application/json',
       'Accept': 'application/json'
     };
  final urlParse = Uri.parse(http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category');
   http.Response response = await http.get(urlParse,headers: header);
```

Comment: I have updated my code with this code. but still have the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the listview builder with Obx or GetBuilder maybe this is just ui error or missing something to show data, If the api have result ang printed it the problem may lie to the ui side state.

Comment: Also try to add headers to http to have Content-type:application/json

Comment: Can you please elaborate how i wrapping the code and how to add content-type. I am quite new and trying to solve this from last two days. If needed i can provide you the `main.dart` file code.

Comment: Sure, Something like this wrapping the code from builder or obx for http add headers

Comment: @MUHTASIMJEET i update from above